# How to push and pull multiple values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I'm pretty new to coding and am running into a roadblock. I'm working on a challenge that I just can't seem to figure out.

```
function createArray() {
  var array = [];
   array.push = function(val){
     array[array.length] = val;
     return array;
   };
   array.pop = function(){
     return array[array.length - 1];
  };

 return array;
 };

var myArray = createArray();
```

When I run the test to complete the challenge, this code seems to push and pop a single value, but it doesn't seem to push and pop multiple values(which is one of the parameters for completing the challenge). Does anyone have any ideas? Possible solution? Any help would be amazing.

Comment: The pop method need to return the last value and remove it from the array

Comment: Your implementation of pop just returns the last value of the array. Pop actually removes the last value of the array and returns it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use Array methods of course, but I thing you can, because you used 
array.length

```
array.pop = function () {
    return array.splice(array.length - 1, 1)[0];
}

array.push = function(value) {
    return array.concat(value)
}
```